# How do you start an animation with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stumped on this one thing. I can't figure out how to start an animation with a button. I'm new to animation so if you could dummy it down it would be easier for me to understand! I don't know jquery too much! I've been looking for hours but can't find what I'm looking for or It's too hard to understand! Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<title>The Wheel!</title>
<body bgcolor="orange">
<head>
    <style>
        .wheel {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            left: 600px;
            top: 300px;
            background: green;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-animation: myfirst 4s 2;
            -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
            animation: myfirst 4s 2;
            animation-direction: alternate;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
            0% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 300px;}
            33% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 0px;}
            66% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 650px;}
            100% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 0px;}
        }

        @keyframes myfirst {
            0% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 300px;}
            33% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 300px;}
            66% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 0px;}
            100% {background: green; left: 600px; top: 650px;}
        }
    </style>      
</head>
    <div class="wheel"></div>
    <button onclick="startbtn">Start</button>

<script>
startbtn = ???;
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another class, then when the button is clicked, get that element with the class `wheel`, then add the new class to it:

```js
startbtn = function() {
  $('.wheel').addClass('animated-wheel');
}
```

```css
.wheel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 600px;
  top: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.animated-wheel {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 4s 2;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: myfirst 4s 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  33% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  66% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 650px;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  33% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  66% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Wheel!</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="orange">
  <div class="wheel"></div>
  <button onclick="startbtn()">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```

To use infinitely many time, use this:

```
.animated-wheel {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 4s infinite; /* infinite can be changed to a number, like 4 or 6 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: myfirst 4s infinite; /* infinite can be changed to a number, like 4 or 6 */
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the animation twice? I could only use It once.

Answer (score 2):

Native javascript is the way to go.

```js
wheel.onmousedown = () => wheel.animate(
 [
   {background: 'green', left: '100px', top: '30px'},
   {background: 'green', left: '120px', top: '40px'},
   {background: 'green', left: '160px', top: '100px'},
   {background: 'blue', left: '100px', top: '30px'}
 ], {
   duration: 3000,
   iterations: Infinity
 }
)
```

```css
.wheelclass {
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem
 }
```

```html
<div class="wheelclass" id="wheel">Native js animation!</div>
```

---

Inline, passing multiple css rules.

Notice the use of a **camel case** for this example rule `font-size`, the camel case replace the dash `fontSize`.

```html
<button id="test" onclick="this.animate([{opacity:.9,fontSize: '8rem' },{opacity:1, fontSize: '1rem'},{opacity: 0.8, fontSize: '1rem'}], {duration: 3000, iterations: 1})">Test!</button>
```

[The web animation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API)

Comment: How can this animation be started with a button?

Comment: Hi, I made a simple modification, same code wrapped in an arrow function. Good luck!

Comment: Simple and Elegant! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery to toggle an class to your div with the class="wheel" like this..

you need first jquery..

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

then you remove the "animation: myfirst 4s 2;" out of your class

create a new class for example

```
.start { animation: myfirst 4s 2;}
```

now you toggle .start to your div box

```
<script>
startbtn(){
$( ".wheel" ).toggleClass( "start" );
 };
</script>
```